# Attribute: Majority single value, but multiple on occasion

Tags: database-design

**Here is the situation:**
There is a dimension with a natural key that is a good candidate for a primary key. However, there are a few columns that can have (and does have - 10% of the time) multiple values. The majority of the data have only one value per key.

**My options:**

1. For the 90%, put it into the table and have "multiple" as the value for the rest; and snowflake the list.
2. Same as #1, but LISTAGG the values. This will make numeric columns - non-numeric.
3. Create a surrogate key, and replicate the rest of the columns with a flag to pick one of the rows - to avoid coding DISTINCT is the attribute is not being used.
4. Just snowflake the column to another table.
5. Any other ideas?

Comment: Presumably by "snowflake a column" you mean remove a list-valued column from a table and add a new table with columns for some key of the original table, a column for list elements and a row for every unique pair of a key value and list element value?